# When I select **Learn more about formatting…** the link does not include $\ce{H2O}$ as an example in Chemistry Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, support

I noticed in one of my answers to [a question about excitation of electrons](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/174343/excitation-of-electrons-from-lower-energy-levels-to-higher-during-covalent-bondi/174351#174351) that the term $\ce{CH4}$ was used. I remember seeing it before in the [Markdown editing page for Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

But now, when I bring up my browser to [that editing page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) and I search with my web browser for "ce", there aren't any instances found on [that page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).  Where did the explanation of this option go?

Comment: I wonder if this is better asked on https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Related (background): *[The* ***mhchem*** *extension has been enabled for chemistry.se](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/which-plugins-for-chemical-formulas-do-we-need/2#comment44_2)* ([more officially](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/enable-mhchem-mathjax-extension/49#49)). [Workaround on Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13118/using-chemical-formulas/13124#13124).

Comment: I really appreciate the link to ** chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com ** ; I had a hard time finding it on Google or on the Chemistry Help page even.  This is probably the same structure for all the various ** stackexchange ** sites.  Thank you!

Comment: @StephenElliott You can find it in the drop-down from the burger menu, top right of your screen on any site.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably thinking of the [Chemistry MathJax FAQ](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/88#88)

That contains the (rather similar) MathJax expression for water

> `The chemical formula of water is $\ce{H2O}$.`

It's linked from [the page you listed](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/editing-help) via

> Learn more: [MathJax help](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/88#88).

Comment: From what I understand, [this link is customizable by site](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6394) but the rest of the page isn't.

Comment: I was noticing that https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting that is the main link on to how to format comments, that this information seems to be missing.  It seems quite essential for chemical formatting so I think that your referenced example should be shown directly there without having to navigate elsewhere, if I understand you correctly.  For me, I have your good answer in my in-box so it is no long a problem.  But, for others, I think that the example you give should be in the direct link also.

Comment: I did see the additional MathJax help link from there, and indeed that is very helpful.  Thank you for your navigational assistance.  To get there is not to hard for me to memorize now.

Answer (score 4):

The root help page on Chemistry now has an example of chemistry markup and a link to the relevant post:

> [image]

For your convenience, here is the URL the link points to: [FAQ: How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86)

Comment: (And for others' reference: Site mods can edit the top section of the main Help Center page on their own site. Karsten is a Chemistry.SE mod.)

Comment: @V2Blast Yes, unless they are on strike ;-)